# Search and extract data from multiple excel files with condition

Tags: vba, excel

so i have my excel file (let`s say test.xlsx) and i have multiple excel files (xlsm) in one folder , they have the same structure ( 5 columns, 60 rows , only the data in them is different), i want to search each file only by columns E and F and if i find a specific value (text) than copy all the text in that specific cell to my file (test.xlsx) if the value is found multiple times in the same file than insert the cell value in the next cell on the same row in my test.xlsx and before moving on to the next file i want it to insert the file name in witch the data was found , in the same row as the data , on the next cell... than as the search moves to the next file i want the data extracted from that to be inserted in a new row and so on.
I have to do this every month and i do this manually , can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that this is not a free coding service. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) But I suggest you one thing: Try to record the macro and then edit the code so it is simple enough and then post it here. Then we can help you solve any bugs you can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - your **Test.xlsx** should be a **xlsm** if your code is in there. All the other files (just with data) - if they have no code - should be **xlsx** instead.

Now - try this code with the above changes in a module in **Test.xlsm**:

```
Sub openFilesExtractData()

    Dim folderPath As String, path As String, yourText As String
    Dim currWbSh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    folderPath = ThisWorkbook.path

    path = folderPath & "\*.xlsx"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    j = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
    k = 1

    Do While Filename <> ""

        If Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Filename <> "" Then

            Workbooks.Open folderPath & "\" & Filename

            Set currWbSh = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)

            yourText = InputBox("What are you searching for?")

            For i = 1 To currWbSh.UsedRange.Rows.count

                Select Case yourText

                    Case currWbSh.Cells(i, 5):

                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, k) = yourText
                        k = k + 1

                    Case currWbSh.Cells(i, 6):

                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, k) = yourText
                        k = k + 1

                End Select

                If i = currWbSh.UsedRange.Rows.count And k <> 1 Then

                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, k) = Filename
                    j = j + 1

                End If

            Next i

            Workbooks(Filename).Close False

        End If

        Filename = Dir()
        k = 1
        j = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

This will open every file in the specified path with a file ending **xlsx**, searching for your inputtext **yourText** and adding the searched text in **A1**. If the same value is found again it'll write it in the next column (same row) and so on; afterwards the name of the opened file is placed in the next column of the same row.